# Proof of the equivalence of PageRank and degree centrality in undirected connected graphs

Tags: graph-theory, stochastic-processes, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-walk, page-rank

Surprisingly, although this is stated everywhere in literature (usually citing surveys), there seems to be no recent source that explicitly proved this statement (there are, however, sources that proved this for a general case where there is damping factor, but the proof cannot be adapted to non-damping scenario).

To define the original problem, suppose that a graph is undirected and connected. Define $d(i)$ as the degree centrality (aka degree) of node $i$, $\mathbf{A}$ the adjacency matrix.  Let $\pmb{w}$ denote the PR vector, and consider PageRank where there is no damping factor, i.e.

$$w(i)=\sum_{j}{A_{ij}\frac{w(j)}{d(j)}}$$

Now we want to prove that $w(i)\propto d(i)$, or $\pmb{w}=\alpha \mathbf{D}\cdot\mathbf{1}$, where $\mathbf{D}$ is the degree diagonal matrix.

I know Perron-Fronebius theorem can tackle this, but I am thinking if there could be a more straightforward proof, possibly solving directly the PageRank equations.

Edit 1:

It looks like Perron-Fronebius cannot directly get the work done because we don't have a strictly positive matrix.  Perhaps should consider proof by contradiction with Chapman-Kolmogorov equations if proving uniqueness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe we can simply input $w = \alpha \cdot D \cdot \mathbf{1}$ into the equation and check that it works. Note that your equation
$$w(i) = \sum_{j} A_{i, j} \frac{w(j)}{d(j)}$$
may be rewritten in matrix terms as:
$$\pmb{w}^T = \pmb{w}^T\mathbf{D}^{-1}A$$
Transposing both sides:
$$\pmb{w} = A\mathbf{D}^{-1}\pmb{w},$$
as both $A$ and $\mathbf{D}$ are symmetric.
Let us insert $\pmb{w} = \alpha \mathbf{D}\cdot \mathbf{1}$ on the right side.
$$\pmb{w} = A\mathbf{D}^{-1}\alpha \mathbf{D}\cdot \mathbf{1}$$
$$\pmb{w} = \alpha A \cdot \mathbf{1}$$
Note that $A\cdot\mathbf{1}$ is a vector of degrees, i.e. $(A \cdot\mathbf{1})_i = \sum_j A_{i, j} = d(i)$. So, we got that
$$\pmb{w} = \alpha \textbf{D}\cdot1,$$
which confirms our assumption.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  Yes this proves $\pmb{w}=\alpha\mathbf{D}\cdot \mathbf{1}$ is at least a solution, but we still need to show the uniqueness of the solution.  If all entries of the matrix are positive, we can leverage Perron-Frobenius, but here it's *non-negative*.  Yet this can still be shown with C-K equations.  Apart from this I am actually trying to see if there is a more straightforward solution (e.g., by directly rearranging the linear system) that a unique solution directly comes out.  Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @jasperhyp Note that $(AD^{-1})^T$ is stochastic, so its largest eigenvalue is $1$, and it must also be the largest eigenvalue of $AD^{-1}$. Now, $A$ is [irreducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Statement), because it is an adjacency matrix of a skeleton of a directed graph associated with the irreducibility conditions of Perron-Frobenius, so $AD^{-1}$ is also irreducible. From this follows that the eigenvalue $1$ of $AD^{-1}$ has eigenspace of dimension $1$, which proves the uniqueness of the solution.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out!  I wasn't aware there is an extension to non-negative irreducible matrix for Perron Fronebius.